# Rendering a private unique page depending on the user's Id

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, backend

just a quick question.
I have a React application running with a server provided by Node.js, and I am using axios to make post requests to my server and save the stuff on the database(login credentials), my question is... How could I render a private unique page for my user depending on his Id, just gimme a topic and I'm gonna learn it, plz.

Comment: What do you mean by a private page?

Comment: Assuming you are using `Express` with node.js then look at [passport](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport)

Comment: Sounds like you want to create a dashboard that is populated with each users' data?

Comment: Yes, that's it, thanks for all the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need both routing and authorization/authentication to make pages 'private'.

react-router can redirect users to their own page with routes like '/users/:id', with the :id being the user's unique id.

You also need to implement authorization, either via sessions or json web tokens. For eg, when users hit the '/users/:id' endpoint, they need to supply something which verifies their identity. This is to prevent users from changing the url in the address bar to access pages not belonging to them (eg user 123 should only be able to access '/users/123' and not '/users/456'.

Have fun learning!

Comment: Thanks for your help !!